# How do you get Client IP Address in a Grails controller?

Tags: grails

I had code like this in Ruby:

```
@clientipaddress = request.env["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]
if (@clientipaddress == nil)
  @clientipaddress = request.env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
end
if (@clientipaddress == nil)
  @clientipaddress = request.env["REMOTE_ADDR"]
end
if (@clientipaddress != nil)
  comma = @clientipaddress.index(",")
  if (comma != nil && comma >= 0)
    @clientipaddress = @clientipaddress[0, comma]
  end
end
```

It took care of all the possible ways that the IP might show up.  For instance, on my local development machine, there is no proxy.  But in QA and Production the proxies are there, and sometimes they provide more than one address.

I don't need to know the Groovy syntax, just which methods get me the equivalent of the three different ways I ask for the IP above.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think this should be what you want:

- `request.getRemoteAddr()`
- `request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")`
- `request.getHeader("Client-IP")`

Comment: I tried this but get: "No such property: request"  have spent 1h googlin this error, no luck. Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: are you doing this inside the controller? This is an injected property and should be there.

Comment: From proxy server, X-Forwarded-For will give you the right value.

Comment: How should be the right way to capture the IP from the valid variable?

Comment: @IgniteCoders: I'm not sure what you mean with that. Can you restate the question?

Comment: I mean that the first line of code gives me the IP, but when should I use the other two lines or methods?

Comment: @IgniteCoders: That depends on what you need this information for. The first line gives you the IP address of the machine from which you're receiving the request, but that can be a proxy server. The other two are ways used by different proxy servers to tell you which machine the request *originally* came from (and now there is also the standardized "Forwarded"-header which has a more complex forrmat). Typically you try the different proxy headers and only if none of those are present you use the remote address.

Answer (score 0):

```
//action in controller 
def postentry (accountno) {
def fulldata = request.reader.text 
def remoteadd = request.getRemoteAddr()
println "ip request  "+remoteadd
...
}
```

result ---ip request  0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained your answer, rather than just dumping some code.