# Disable user authentication in grails' spring-security-core plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm looking to add some security to my small service written on Grails: restriction by IP, force HTTPS and maybe something more later.

So I've added spring-security-core dependency

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'
```

to my build.gradle and something like this

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = ['/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ipRestrictions = ['/**': ['127.0.0.1', '%MY-OFFICE-IP-HERE%']]
```

to my Config.groovy.

Service is quite simple, it only has two controllers that return some data in JSON format. But spring-security-core plugin by default adds user authentication: login page, logout interceptor, access denied handler and so on. I don't need such functionality at this time and want to disable it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your Config.groovy for development environment:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = false
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it seems your solution disables the whole spring-security-core plugin, including ip restriction and secure channel definition.

Comment: Sorry @user24809, I misunderstood your question. What do you really want to have when some user tries to access outside of the IP since you want to disable the authentication system?

Comment: It's simple: return 403 HTTP status code if the IP from `request.remoteAddr` is not allowed (not in the specified list of addresses/masks). At this time I'm using plain Grails filter, but I want to do it with spring-security-core.

Answer (score 0):

so what you are saying is you just want IP restriction but not roles, securing your controllers/methods or any actual security for your application because it's in the DMZ???

Then you don't want Spring-security, just implement something like this... [How do you get Client IP Address in a Grails controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140859/how-do-you-get-client-ip-address-in-a-grails-controller)

detect IP in filter and reject if it doesn't match acceptable IP's in config

Comment: I've done it already, but that's a temporary solution. It seems that the service will require x509 authentication in the nearest future, so I had to use spring-security-core anyway.

Comment: Yes then you want to implement spring security then. You are asking to have your cake and eat it to but you need to implement roles and security as well. This is why Spring-security-core is such a great all-in-one solution.