# get XFF using angular

Tags: angular, grails

I need to get Client's IP to define their role in my website.

I already asked similar question here [Get client IP address Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77999322/23410654) but failed to do so.

I read that X_FORWARDED_FOR includes client's ip and proxy. I tried to get XFF from frontend but failed. Or XFF can only be accessed from backend?

Is it possible to get Client's IP from frontend? or I need to get it from the backend (I use grails)?
Or maybe anyone have tips to how I can get Client's IP (either i get it from frontend or backend)

I'm a newbie frontend developer and need help. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get Client IP Address in a Grails controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140859/how-do-you-get-client-ip-address-in-a-grails-controller)